# Invalid Storage Type: DBNull

Tags: c#, .net, datatable, datarow, expando

When using expando objects to fill my datatable, I am facing following error message when I initialize a new `datarow`. The exception is:

> Invalid Storage Type: DBNull

```
public static DataTable ToCLDataTable<T>(List<T> items)
{
    DataTable dataTable = new DataTable("CLWorkQueue");
    //Get all the properties
    DataRow dr;

    var expandoDict = items[0] as IDictionary<string, object>;
    foreach (var key in expandoDict.Keys)
    {
        if ((expandoDict[key]).GetType() == typeof(DateTime))
        {
            dataTable.Columns.Add(key.ToString(), typeof(DateTime));
        }
        else
        {
            dataTable.Columns.Add(key.ToString(), expandoDict[key].GetType());
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < items.Count; i++)
    {
        var expandoDictData = items[i] as IDictionary<string, object>;
        //var values = new object[expandoDictData.Count];
        int j = 0;
        dr = dataTable.NewRow(); /*Though the datatable has all the required columns, but whenever i try to initialize a new row an exception occurs.*/
        foreach (var key in expandoDictData.Keys)
        {
            //values[j] = expandoDictData[key].ToString();
            dr[key] = expandoDictData[key].ToString();
            j++;
        }
        dataTable.Rows.Add(dr);
        //dataTable.Rows.Add(values);
    }[enter image description here][1]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value of the first result in your `items[0]` was `DBNull.Vaue`  - which is what your SQL client populated into the structure. That's what the SQL client uses to indicate a null value. So, the actual *type* of the object in the first `Value` of the `IDictionary<String,object>` is `DBNull`...not the type it would have been if there had been a value. You might have to iterate your dictionary until you get a value before you can add that column to the datarow...or come up with a more bulletproof way of assigning the type to the column.